# Ogr2ogr driver error when convert shapefile to mif

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I use the following script to convert shapefile to mif:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" D:\docs\arcgis_data\shp_mif\BOU.mif D:\docs\arcgis_data\shp\BOU.shp
```

But I got the error:

```
ERROR 6: Unable to open D:\docs\arcgis_data\shp_mif\BOU.mif
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Does the D:\docs\arcgis_data\shp_mif directory exist?

Comment: Oh, thank you, the directory does not exist, I create it manually and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MapInfo TAB and MIF/MID driver documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_mitab.html), you may also need to specify also the dataset creation option `-dsco FORMAT=MIF` in order *to create `MIF/MID` instead of `TAB` files (`TAB` is the default)*:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" -dsco FORMAT=MIF D:\docs\arcgis_data\shp_mif\BOU.mif D:\docs\arcgis_data\shp\BOU.shp
```

You can also add the `-overwrite` option if the `MIF` file already exists.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, it seems that my problem is caused by the missed directory.